# how to get a list of files using only the C standard library

Tags: c

I need to display the names of the files in a specified directory. How can I do this using only C standard function?

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: The short answer is: "You can't." Standard C simply doesn't include that capability. You need to use something else (e.g., POSIX/SUS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no portable way to list all the files in a specified directory using only the C Standard library.

Functions like `readdir` are part of POSIX but not part of the C Standard library.

You have to remember that not all operating systems have a concept of directory. An example is the MVS OS on IBM System/360 and System/370 where "." was used in file names to represents a directory hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you, could you then write the easiest way to implement this task. (For example, if using POSIX)

Answer (score 3):

Short of calling `fopen()` on every filename permutation you can think of, **there is no standard way** to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dirent` API:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirent.h
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/dirent.h.html

Comment: Do note, however, that dirent is POSIX only. There seems to be an implementation available for Windows, but that still means it's not using purely "C standard" functions.

Comment: It depends on what do you call "C standard". I would go for dirent.h, as 1. "Posix C library" is an existing standard, 2. do you know any simpler solution which is more standard? I'm certain you don't consider the proprietary Windows API stuff <<standard>>...

Comment: @H2CO3 `dirent` is NOT a part of the C Standard library. For functions   that are part of the C Standard library, see section 7. Library in the C Standard.

Comment: Don't teach me what the standard is (in addition, why on Earth are you downvoting this?). There's no better or more standard way to do this, and instead of telling the OP "You can't do this", I wanted to help, you see?

Comment: @H2CO3: describing the Posix way to do it is helpful. Describing the Windows way would also be helpful. Calling Posix functions "C standard" is not helpful. Any fool can define *a* standard, and it might include some C functions. That doesn't make them part of *the* C standard or the C standard library.